# To show JSON returned error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I needs to show the ***Json*** returned message.

In the controller, an exception is thrown and caught in a catch block. I am returning the fault error message.

In ***Ajax***, the *success* part always executes. But if it is an error from my ***webservice***, I don't want to execute the normal; instead I want to show an error message.

How I can achieve this?

My code below:

### Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DeleteClientRecord()
{

    bool result = true;
    try
    {
        result = ClientCRUDCollection.DeleteClient(deleteClientId);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        return Json(ex.Message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return Json(new { result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

### AJAX Call

```
$("#YesDelete").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "/Client/DeleteClientRecord",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (request) {
            alert(request.responseText);
            event.preventDefault();
        },
        success: function (result) {
            // if error from webservice I want to differentiate here somehow
            $("#Update_" + id).parents("tr").remove();
            $('#myClientDeleteContainer').dialog('close');
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Please can anyone help me on this.

Comment: If server returns status `200` then `success` will get executed. If you want the error handler to execute then you need to return a error code like `500`, `400`, etc. Sorry I don't know how to do it in ASP

Comment: @DarinDimitrov is right. Your alert should be alert(result.Message) because that is how my example named the message member of the return object

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DeleteClientRecord()


{

         bool result = true;
         try
         {
            result = ClientCRUDCollection.DeleteClient(deleteClientId);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            return Json(new { Success="False", responseText=ex.Message});
         }

    return Json(new { result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. In success part of ajax I tried to print the message as  alert(result.message); But getting null. I want to check for any error condition and display the exception message.

Comment: You should try `alert(result.Message)` instead of `alert(result.message)` because that's how the property is named.

Comment: @vishnureghu, I changed my code to return message in responseText as you use in your alert. I wasnt careful in looking at your JQ code. DD pointed it out. Try this example.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I Will try and let you know.

Comment: .net Core: return new JsonResult(new { Success = "False", test222 = "sdf" });

Answer (score 1):

to show error message, you should add error scope after success scope in AJAX call like this:

```
$("#YesDelete").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "/Client/DeleteClientRecord",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (request) {
            alert(request.responseText);
            event.preventDefault();
        },
        success: function (result) {
            // if error from webservice I want to differentiate here somehow
            $("#Update_" + id).parents("tr").remove();
            $('#myClientDeleteContainer').dialog('close');
            return false;
        }
        error: function (xhr) {alert(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message); }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add Response.StatusCode to the response

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
```